Tailwind safelist for dynamic custom classes
Basically, I'm using iconfiy with tailwind and addDynamicIconSelectors(), where you are supposed to add icon as classes like this 'className = 'icon-[icon-name]'', and I have a custom component that accepts that name of the class and adds it to a div with the above className.
The issue is: Tailwind is purging most (not all, for example 'mdi:heart' is working fine) classes and I see no icons, the icon component was already used many times in many components and pages and now I'm just updating it, since before I used the iconfity react component but it was causing a weird loading issue in next js where you see icons pop up, that's why I switched to Tailwind.
This is my component:


import { cn } from '@/lib/utils'

type IconI = {
  name?: string
  className?: string
  width?: string | number
  rotate?: number
  hFlip?: boolean
  vFlip?: boolean
} & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>

const Icon: React.FC<IconI> = ({
  name,
  className,
  width,
  rotate,
  hFlip,
  vFlip,
  ...props
}) => {
  // replace : in names with --

  const generateIconName = (name: string) => {
    if (!name) return ''
    const tempName = name.replace(/:/g, '--')
    console.log(`Generated icon class: icon-[${tempName}]`)
    return `icon-[${tempName}]`
  }

  return <span className={cn(generateIconName(name ?? ''), className)} />
}

export default Icon



I have been messing around with safelist and for example if I add 'mdi:tag' directly to safe list the icon works, but if I add a pattern that excludes 'icon-[' for example, it doesn't, what is the best approach to take?
This is my Tailwind config


import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'
const { addDynamicIconSelectors } = require('@iconify/tailwind')

const config = {
  // mode: 'jit',
  // purge: ['./public/**/*.html', './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}'],

  // content: [
  //   './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}', // Note the addition of the `app` directory.
  //   './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  //   './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',

  //   // Or if using `src` directory:
  //   './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  // ],
  // darkMode: 'class',

  darkMode: ['class'],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: {
        DEFAULT: '15px',
        sm: '15px',
        lg: '15px',
        xl: '0',
        '2xl': '0',
      },
      screens: {
        sm: '640px',
        md: '768px',
        lg: '1024px',
        xl: '1280px',
        '2xl': '1440px',
        '3xl': '1600px',
      },
    },

    extend: {
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        // 24 column grid
        20: 'repeat(20, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      },
      screens: {
        sm: '640px',
        md: '768px',
        lg: '1024px',
        xl: '1280px',
        '2xl': '1550px',
        '3xl': '1800px',
      },
      fontSize: {
        'heading-3xl': '5.5rem',
        'heading-2xl': '4.5rem',
        'heading-xl': '3.5rem',
        'heading-lg': '2.5rem',
        'heading-md': '2.25rem',
        'heading-sm': '2rem',
        'heading-xs': '1.75rem',
        'heading-2xs': '1.5rem',
        'heading-3xs': '1.25rem',
        'paragraph-lg': '1rem',
        'paragraph-md': '0.875rem',
        'paragraph-sm': '0.75rem',
        'paragraph-xs': '0.625rem',
        s: '0.825rem',
        '2xs': '0.625rem',
        '3xs': '0.5rem',
      },
      colors: {
        primary: '#072A1F',
        secondary: '#000000',
        danger: {
          50: '#FFF7F7',
          100: '#FEEFEF',
          200: '#FCD6D7',
          300: '#FABBBD',
          400: '#F68B8D',
          500: '#F1595C',
          600: '#D75052',
          700: '#913638',
          800: '#6D292A',
          900: '#461A1B',
        },
        black: {
          50: '#F9FAFB',
          100: '#F4F5F7',
          200: '#E5E7EB',
          300: '#D2D6DC',
          400: '#9FA6B2',
          500: '#111112',
          600: '#475569',
          700: '#334155',
          800: '#1E293B',
          900: '#0F172A',
        },
        warning: {
          50: '#FFFAF8',
          100: '#FFF4F1',
          200: '#FEE4DA',
          300: '#FDD2C3',
          400: '#FCB298',
          500: '#FA916B',
          600: '#DF8260',
          700: '#965741',
          800: '#714231',
          900: '#492B20',
        },
        blue: {
          light: '#40DCFE',
        },
        cyan: {
          primary: '#00FFF0',
        },
        info: {
          50: '#F3FEFF',
          100: '#E7FEFF',
          200: '#C5FDFF',
          300: '#A3FCFF',
          400: '#5FF9FF',
          500: '#0CE7FA',
          600: '#00B8D4',
          700: '#007A8D',
          800: '#005E67',
          900: '#003F42',
        },
        success: {
          50: '#F3FEF8',
          100: '#E7FDF1',
          200: '#C5FBE3',
          300: '#A3F9D5',
          400: '#5FF5B1',
          500: '#50C793',
          600: '#3F9A7A',
          700: '#2E6D61',
          800: '#1F4B47',
          900: '#0F2A2E',
        },
        gray: {
          50: '#F9FAFB',
          100: '#F4F5F7',
          200: '#E5E7EB',
          300: '#D2D6DC',
          400: '#9FA6B2',
          500: '#68768A',
          600: '#475569',
          700: '#334155',
          800: '#1E293B',
          900: '#0F172A',
          primary: '#B4B4B4',
          secondary: '#FCFCFC',
          secondaryDark: '#F7F7F7',
          light: '#F3F3F3',
          lighter: '#F8F8F8',
        },
        red: {
          secondary: '#FF114A',
          secondaryLightest: '#FFF1F3',
        },
        orange: {
          primary: '#FE852E',
        },

        purple: {
          primary: '#5145DD',
        },
        yellow: {
          primary: '#FDD60C',
        },
        pink: {
          primary: '#FF1276',
        },
        green: {
          primary: '#2FB98E',
          primaryLight: '#45DD82',
          secondary: '#072A1F',
        },
      },

      fontFamily: {
        inter: ['Inter', 'sans-serif'],
        GilroyBold: ['var(--font-GilroyBold)', 'sans-serif'],
        GilroyHeavy: ['var(--font-GilroyHeavy)', 'sans-serif'],
        GilroyLight: ['var(--font-GilroyLight)', 'sans-serif'],
        GilroyMedium: ['var(--font-GilroyMedium)', 'sans-serif'],
        GilroyRegular: ['var(--font-GilroyRegular)', 'sans-serif'],
        ChroniBlack: ['var(--font-ChroniBlack)', 'sans-serif'],
        ChroniLight: ['var(--font-ChroniLight)', 'sans-serif'],
        ChroniSemiBold: ['var(--font-ChroniSemiBold)', 'sans-serif'],
        PetitFormal: ['var(--font-PetitFormal)', 'sans-serif'],
        SyncoRegular: ['var(--font-SyncopateRegular)', 'sans-serif'],
        SyncoBold: ['var(--font-SyncopateBold)', 'sans-serif'],
        Montserrat: ['var(--font-MontserratFont)', 'sans-serif'],
        MontserratBold: ['var(--font-MontserratBold)', 'sans-serif'],
        MontserratSemiBold: ['var(--font-MontserratSemiBold)', 'sans-serif'],
        MontserratMedium: ['var(--font-MontserratMedium)', 'sans-serif'],
        // add weight to the array
        MontserratRegular: ['var(--font-MontserratRegular)', 'sans-serif'],
        MontserratLight: ['var(--font-MontserratLight)', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      boxShadow: {
        base: '0px 0px 1px rgba(40, 41, 61, 0.08), 0px 0.5px 2px rgba(96, 97, 112, 0.16)',
        base2:
          '0px 2px 4px rgba(40, 41, 61, 0.04), 0px 8px 16px rgba(96, 97, 112, 0.16)',
        base3: '16px 10px 40px rgba(15, 23, 42, 0.22)',
        deep: '-2px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)',
        dropdown: '0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)',
        testi: '0px 4px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)',
        todo: 'rgba(235 233 241, 0.6) 0px 3px 10px 0px',
      },
      keyframes: {
        zoom: {
          '0%, 100%': { transform: 'scale(0.5)' },
          '50%': { transform: 'scale(1)' },
        },
        tada: {
          '0%': { transform: 'scale3d(1, 1, 1)' },
          '10%, 20%': {
            transform: 'scale3d(1, 1, 0.95) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg)',
          },
          '30%, 50%, 70%, 90%': {
            transform: 'scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg)',
          },
          '40%, 60%, 80%': {
            transform: 'rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg)',
          },
          '100%': { transform: 'scale3d(1, 1, 1)' },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        'spin-slow': 'spin 3s linear infinite',
        zoom: 'zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite',
        tada: 'tada 1.5s ease-in-out infinite',
      },
    },
  },
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /^icon-\[.+\]$/,
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss-animate'),
    addDynamicIconSelectors({
      iconPrefix: 'icon-',
    }),
  ],
} satisfies Config

export default config




According to their docs, addDynamicIconSelectors doesn't seem to have an iconPrefix parameter, and the prefix parameter doesn't contain the -.

Do u find the solution?

I believe this question is the same as this one?
You might just be having a problem with the regex. Try some javascript regex builder online and make sure your exact classes are matching the regex you provide? I used regexr to verify this one.
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    { pattern: /^icon-\[[a-z]{3}--[a-z-]+\]$/ },
    // …
  ],
  // …
}

This config will safe list classes such as icon-[mdi--heart] and icon-[mdi--heart-big-solid] but not icon-[mi--heart] (because of the {3}) or icon-[mdi--heart_solid] (because of the _).
But even better than the safe list IMO is to use the dictionary approach in that answer and have the desired classes all spelled out right there in the component, or else the next time someone edits the classes it might break again.

the icon have to be of the format icon-[iconPrefix--iconName], and tailwind says safelist regex works only for base tailwind classes, thats why im thinking my current regex isnt working, also the different between that post and mine is he is using bg, which is a base tailwind class, mine isnt

I think it's just talking about base classes vs variants, which you need to list like this: safelist: [     'text-2xl',     'text-3xl',     {       pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue)-(100|200|300)/,       variants: ['lg', 'hover', 'focus', 'lg:hover'],     },   ],

Try https://github.com/spatie/tailwind-safelist-generator ?
